# Ubuntu equalizer

Tags: equalizer

How can I simply install a simple equalizer? I need to make my loudspeakers a little bit louder. I saw that there are one popular but you need to do some magic in order to make it work. Can someone just post a simple way to install a simple equalizer? Ubuntu is 20.04, I don't want to do any magic, it's just an equalizer, why can't I just install a simple one with a simple way.

Comment: No magic whatsoever. And for the intended purpose no equalizer required either. Ubuntu already provides an optional setting for over-amplification.

Comment: @ChanganAuto, by "magic" I mean additional setup things you need to do before it will work, and didn't know about this option, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu already provides an optional setting for over-amplification in `Settings > Sound`